# Android GestureDetector cannot detect onScroll event with FrameLayout

Tags: android, scroll, touch-event, android-custom-view, android-framelayout

I have a view that extends FrameLayout and need to be notified of the scrolling events on it.
this view has an instance of a class that implements the GestureDetector which is invoked by the overriden onInterceptTouchEvent method.

```
    private class HorizontalScrollListener implements OnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        ...
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) { 
         ...
         return false; 
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) { 
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        ...
        System.out.println();
    }
    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) { return false; }
}
```

The only problem is that the onDown and onLongPress methods could get called wheen I try to scroll but the actual onScroll methods never gets invoked.

```
    @Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean result = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);

    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Did you try to return true from onDown()?

Comment: Yes, But it it never reaches to onScroll(..)

Comment: Sorry I cannot give you an answer but according to my tests onInterceptTouchEvent does not receive all touch events but only the initial down event. Therefore the GestureDetector cannot do its work. (Try adding debug output to the method.) According to the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) one has to return false to receive all following events but this does not seem to be true.

Answer (score 2):

`onInterceptTouchEvent` is not called again for a motion sequence once it returns `true`. Events are sent to `onTouchEvent` directly afterwards (since they are now being intercepted from the children).

You need two changes here:

- `OnGestureListener.onDown()` should return `true` so the detector can process more complex gestures like scrolls
- `onInterceptTouchEvent` should always return `false` to keep the stream of events flowing to this method